# strange behavior of fc -l command

Tags: unix, shell, ksh

I have two unix machines, both running AIX 5.3
My $HOME is mounted on machine1.
Using NFS, login machine2 will go to the same $HOME

I login machine2 first, then machine1.
Both using telnet.

The 2 sessions will share the same .sh_history file.

I found out that the fc -l behavior very strange.

In machine2, I issue the commands in telnet:

```
fc -l  
ksh fc -l
```

Both give the same output.

In machine1,

```
fc -l  
ksh fc -l
```

give DIFFERENT results
The result for `ksh fc -l`
is the same as `/usr/bin/fc -l`

Also, when I run a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh  
fc -l
```

The result is same as `/usr/bin/fc -l`

Could anyone tell me what happened?

Alvin SIU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the login shell is not ksh or that `$HISTFILE` is being reset. One thing you can do is `echo $HISTFILE` in the various situations and see if it's different. Another thing to check is to see what shell you're in using `ps`.

Bash (default `$HOME/.bash_history`), for example, will have a different `$HISTFILE` than ksh (default `$HOME/.sh_history`).

Another possible reason for the difference is that the builtin `fc` may be able to see in-memory history that hasn't been written to disk yet (which the external `/usr/bin/fc` wouldn't be able to see). If this is true, it may be version dependent. Bash, for example, doesn't write history to the file until the shell exits. Ksh (at least the version I'm using) writes it immediately.

Comment: I am sure that I am running ksh.  I am sure that the $HISTFILE is not set.  Because the /etc/profile calls a script which use function, this make ksh to write to command history file .sh_history.  My .profile cannot overwrite the command history using HISTFILE variables.  So, I simply do not set the HISTFILE.  Therefore, the conclusion may be due to in-memory history.  Is there any way to force my login ksh not to use in-memory history ?

Comment: @Alvin: I think ksh writes to the history file immediately (it's only an issue with Bash). Only interactive shells (normally) write to the history file - scripts usually don't. What exactly do you see happening and what is it that you're trying to do? What are you referring to when you say that a script which uses functions causes ksh to write to the history file when called from `/etc/profile`? I don't see that behavior.

Comment: What I mean is that we have to set $HISTFILE before the function call/definition.  Since the /etc/profile has call some script which define function, this make the /etc/profile to use .sh_history for my login shell.  I cannot use $HISTFILE to override the command history file in my .profile. ---------- For what exactly I see ?  Actually, fc -l will have a number before each command.  The fc -l give a number 3xx.  The /usr/bin/fc -l give a number 1xx.  This is why I also suspect that in-memory history is not yet written to .sh_history

Answer (score 1):

Ah, wisdom of the ancients...  (Since this post is over a year old.)

Anyway, I just encountered this problem in Solaris 10.  Issue seems to be this:  When you define a function in `/etc/profile`, or in any file called by `/etc/profile`, your `HISTFILE` variable gets ignored by the Korn shell, and the shell instead uses `".sh_history"` when accessing its history.  Not sure why this is.

Result is that you see other root shell's commands.  You can test it with :

```
lsof -p $$
```

or

```
cat /proc/$$/fd/63
```